# How do I limit a text length and add dots to show continuation python django

Tags: python, django

Am working on an Ecommerce website using django. My problem is that some products name are longer that the other, which makes the product display look odd.

**Question:** How do I limit the length of product name and add dots to show that it continue

Example: 
 `product_name = "Men Suede Loafers Moccasins Shoes -Black"`

will look like
   `product_name = "Men Suede Loafers Mocca...."`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`|truncatechars`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars):

```
{{ product_name|truncatechars:23 }}
```

While you thus store the `product_name` as full text, it is *rendered* for the first 23 characters, and then followed by an ellipsis (…).

You can also add a tooltip that shows the text in full, for example:

```
<p title="{{ product_name }}">{{ product_name|truncatechars:23 }}</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) save() method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if len(self.product_name) > 20:
        self.product_name = self.product_name[:20] + '...'
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the length of a string using `len`

You can cut a string up using slices `[:]`

You can add the ellipsis to a string if the length is longer than a certain threshold.

```
if len(product_name) > 15:
    product_name = product_name[:15] + "..."
```